# Javascript typed variables name/syntax/reference?

Tags: javascript, types

I am trying to find the reference on how to declare typed variables in JavaScript. I know I've seen it somwhere, but I cannot find any reference for it, nor can I remember the "correct" term for it. e.g.:

```
var name: string = "Ian Boyd";
```

- I don't know if I saw it on the IEBlog, and it was in the works for the next version of Javascript
- I don't know if it's something only available in `"use strict"` mode
- I don't know if it's something that's been available for a while

All I know is that I saw it; and I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 5):

No, that syntax doesn't exist in pure JavaScript. JavaScript is a loosely-typed language, even in ECMAScript 5 strict mode.

You may have seen it in *ActionScript*, a relative of JavaScript used in Flash scripting:

```
var someVariable:TypeName = someValue;

function someFunc():ReturnType {
}

// etc.
```

is all valid in ActionScript. ActionScript also has classes.